# Update android widget on condition

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, onupdate

I'm just starting with android development and have written an application to show details about the battery status.
Now I wanted to put the whole thing into an widget - and here's the question:
Do I really need a update service in the background to listen for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intents? My first thought was to put just a 

line into the intet-filter tag of the widget in the AndroidManifest.xml - but obviously it's not that simple.
If the UpdateService is the right way I'll do so - but I just wanted to make sure what the proper solution is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I really need a update service in
>   the background to listen for
>   ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intents?

You cannot use a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. It can only be registered by an activity or service via `registerReceiver()`.

If you do not have a service in memory for other reasons, a better approach is to poll. Set up an `AlarmManager` to check the battery level every so often (configurable, please!). To check the battery level, call `registerReceiver()` for an `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` `IntentFilter` without a `BroadcastReceiver` (`null` for the first parameter). This will return the last-broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` `Intent`, from which you can get the most-recent charge level.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you poll the battery status periodically, e.g. every 30 min. To do that you can simply specify a value for [`updatePeriodMillis`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis) in your [`AppWidgetProviderInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html)

```
<appwidget-provider
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" />
```

..and update your widget by overriding the [`onUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onUpdate) method of your [`AppWidgetProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html).

edit: As pointed out by Martin, 30 min is actually the shortest interval in which you can receive updates this way.

Comment: thanks for that - but that would be limited to at least 30 minutes since this is the minimum value for updatePeriodMillis, won't it?

Comment: You are right! That's very interesting, because this limitation has not always been there (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=commit;h=851da848e97d9a1ec23a89ff0e200c301f32d690)

Comment: I recon it was introduced because programmers used it to make frequent updates (like every second for clock-widgets) - which probably isn't a good thing for battery-life

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, the following works:

```
cont.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(rec, filter);
```